# Proof of $\tanh(x/2) = \coth x - \operatorname{cosech}x$

Tags: trigonometry

> Show that
>   $$
> \tanh\frac{x}{2} = \coth x - \operatorname{cosech}x
> $$
>   where $x\ne 0$.

I get 
$$
\frac{e^x+e^{-x}-2}{e^x-e^{-x}}
$$
but I can't show that is equal to $\tanh (x/2)$.

Comment: In such cases convert to circular functions $ x  \rightarrow i x ; \, (1- \cos( 2.. ) /\sin (..) $ and then switch back to hyperbolic functions avoiding exp altogether.

Answer (score 1):

you have to prove that
$$\frac{e^{1/2x}-e^{-1/2x}}{e^{1/2x}+e^{-1/2x}}=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}-\frac{2}{e^x-e^{-x}}$$
by crossmultiplication we get $$e^{3/2x}-e^{-1/2x}-e^{1/2x}+e^{-3/2x}=e^{3/2x}-e^{-1/2x}-e^{1/2x}+e^{-3/2x}$$
which is true.

Comment: Did you mean by crossmultiple the RHS and LHS ?

Comment: yes i meant the denominators

Answer (score 1):

$$
\coth(x)-\mathrm{csch}(x) = 
\frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}-1}-\frac{2}{e^x-e^{-x}} =
\frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}-1}-\frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}-1} =\\
\frac{e^{2x}-2e^x+ 1}{e^{2x}-1} =
\frac{(e^{x}-1)^2}{(e^{x}-1)(e^x+1)} =
\frac{e^{x}-1}{e^{x}+1} = \tanh\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

The right-hand side is
$$
\frac{\cosh x}{\sinh x}-\frac{1}{\sinh x}=
\frac{\cosh x-1}{\sinh x}
$$
Recall that $\cosh2t=\cosh^2t+\sinh^22t$ and $\sinh2t=2\sinh t\cosh t$, so we get
$$
=\frac{\cosh^2(x/2)+\sinh^2(x/2)-1}{2\sinh(x/2)\cosh(x/2)}=
\frac{2\sinh^2(x/2)}{2\sinh(x/2)\cosh(x/2)}
$$
because $\cosh^2t-1=\sinh^2t$.

Comment: Oh so is not a must for us to solve this question in the form of exponential. I did solve the question by using this method.

Comment: @user365442 The method with $e^x$ is good as well. This is just another possibility.